# PHP replace all spaces with hyphens

Tags: php

I replace all spaces with hyphens in my script like this:

```
$final = str_replace(' ','-',$final); The - is the only thing I replace.
```

What I'm replacing are `Band Name - Song Name` So in this case, if I had something like:

```
Metallica - Hero of the Day
```

I end up with:

```
 Metallica---Hero-of-the-Day
```

Notice the 3 `---` there?

Can you suggest an elegant way of ending up with just one `-` instead of 3.

I can keep doing str_replace until it's done, but that doesn't see right.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a regular expression changing multiple spaces or hyphens with one hyphen:

```
$final = preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', $text);
```

Comment: `$final = preg_replace('#[ -]+#', '-', trim($text))`; worked for me