# MySql replacing spaces with hyphens

Tags: mysql

A day ago, I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890940/php-replace-all-spaces-with-hyphens) on stackoverflow. Sure, that works well, but does anyone know how I can do the same thing in a MySql statement without any php involved?

Eg: `select preg_replace(:songName,' ', '-') //Ugh, this is wrong.`

What I'm trying to do Is replace `spaces` with a `-`. But sometimes, when there is a space, I'll get more `-`

Eg: `Metallica - Hero of the Day` ends up as `Metallica---Hero-of-the-Day`

Any chance of making it just: `Metallica-Hero-of-the-Day`

BTW: It's not only song names I'm replacing.

I'm ok with a simple MySql replace, but I can see doing the above is going to need more than that.

Comment: as you know how to use replace for mysql do as follow: replace every `-` for a space, then two spaces for none spaces then one space for a `-`

Answer (score 3):

I would replace spaces with hyphens first, then deal with any multiple hyphens that may have been created:

```
select replace(replace(replace(songTitle, ' ', '-'), '---', '-'), '--', '-')
```

I've replaced `---` and `--` separately because there are edge cases which overall would require both, and in that order.

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24982)

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan that was a typo on my part. Corrected now - see fiddle. NOTE: the hyphen in your fiddle was *not* a standard hyphen - it's a weird Microsoft dash character, which will not be replaced by my code. I changed the character for my fiddle

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan now the whitespace character between "Hero" and "of" is not a space! (It's a tab or a non-breaking space... who knows). Manually type in your examples - don't copy paste from a Microsoft special character infested filename.

Comment: those were pure white spaces. but 9 concecutive. thats all

Answer (score 2):

Use a user defined function like this(use delimetres accordingly)

```
CREATE FUNCTION replace_spaceWithHyphen(textToReplace varchar(100))
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE occHyphen int; 
DECLARE occSpace int; 
set occHyphen = 1;
set occSpace = 1;
WHILE (occHyphen <> 0 || occSpace <> 0) DO
        SELECT LOCATE('--',textToReplace) into occHyphen;
        SELECT LOCATE(' ',textToReplace) into occSpace;
        SELECT REPLACE(textToReplace,' ','-') into textToReplace;
        SELECT REPLACE(textToReplace,'--','-') into textToReplace;
    END WHILE;
  RETURN textToReplace;
END;
```

Then call your select like this:

```
SELECT replace_spaceWithHyphen('Metallica - Hero of the Day');
```

Answer would be:

```
TEXT
Metallica-Hero-of-the-Day
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7ab4/1)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select 
replace(
replace(
replace('Metallica - Hero of the Day', '-', ' ')
  , '  ', '')
  , ' ', '-')
```

Comment: There's no way to use something like a preg_replace in MySQL as we did in the previous answer?

Comment: You can use a UDF (User Defined Function) to do this. Pure Mysql You cant as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You may write your query. It is so easy for you.

Suppose you have a table named class(id, classname) with two fields. Now you insert in your table in classname field i.e. Metallica - Hero of the Day.

**Now you can execute this by below given program.**

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('dbname');            // Please insert your dbname

$query = mysql_query('SELECT classname, REPLACE(classname," ","-") from class');
$record = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $record['REPLACE(classname," ","-")'];
```

It will give output. i.e. Metallica---Hero-of-the-Day.

**and if you replace your query with.** I have taken help from Bohemian answer for below query.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT classname, replace(replace(replace(classname, ' ', '-'), '---', '-'), '--', '') from class");
$record = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $record["replace(replace(replace(classname, ' ', '-'), '---', '-'), '--', '')"];
```

You will get result i.e. Metallica-Hero-of-the-Day

That's it. Easy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, old_value, new_value);
```

For Example

```
UPDATE TABLENAME SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, '-', ' ');
```

Hope this will helps you.